# Java junit assert that an exception has thrown

Tags: java, junit

Is one better than the other? if so, for what reasons?
I am leaning towards the first because i can understand what the test is trying to much more quickly.

If so, when should one be using `assertThrows()`?

```
@Test(expected=CustomException.class)
public void test_one() {
   execute()
}
```

vs.

```
@Test
public void test_one() {
    assertThrows(CustomException.class, () -> execute());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have your test this way:

```
@Test
public void test_one() {
   execute1();
   execute2()
}
```

Assume you want to check `CustomException` thrown by execute2().

Now if you go with the first approach, and `execute1()` throws the `CustomException` test will still pass and you won't be able to know whether it was thrown by `execute2()` or not.

But with the second approach you can specify that you want to make sure that exception is thrown by `execute2()` method call, hence test will only pass when the `CustomException` is thrown by `execute2()` method.